# dialog witch dynamically changing labeled as progress

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like dialog that dynamically changed its label as its progress without dissapering. I had a look on UserDialogs and that have a progress only with numbers.
So I have tried something like this but that just uses the last set up for label.
Can you please advise is there any Nuget that I have missed or do you know how to do it?

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject 
        {
            private bool _isVisible;
            public bool IsVisible
            {
    
                set
                {
                    _isVisible = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
    
                }
                get => _isVisible;
            }
    
            private string _loadingText = "test";
            public string LoadingText
            {
    
                set
                {
                    _loadingText = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
    
                }
                get => _loadingText;
            }
    
            public ViewModel()
            {
                _isVisible = true;
                _loadingText = "test";
                test();
            }
    
            public void test()
            {
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                _loadingText = "tst20";
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                _loadingText = "tst8";
            }
    
        }
    
    <ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="App1.LoadingDialog">
      <ContentView.Content>
            <Frame
                            CornerRadius="10"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                            IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <StackLayout>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                                    IsRunning="{Binding IsVisible}"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible}"
                                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                                    Color="#607D8B" />
                    <Label
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    Text="{Binding LoadingText}"
                                    TextColor="#000000"
                                    XAlign="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>
        </ContentView.Content>
    </ContentView>
    
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
                 x:Class="App1.MainPage">
    
        <StackLayout>
            <local:LoadingDialog/>
        </StackLayout>
    
    </ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like dialog that dynamically changed its label as its progress without dissapering

I use [Bindableproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties) to do this, you can take a look:

LoadingDialog.xaml.

```
<ContentView
x:Class="FormsSample.customcontrol.LoadingDialog"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
<ContentView.Content>
    <Frame
        x:Name="frame"
        BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
        CornerRadius="10"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator
                x:Name="acin"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Color="#607D8B" />
            <Label
                x:Name="label1"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                TextColor="#000000"
                XAlign="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

Code behind:

```
 public partial class LoadingDialog : ContentView
{
    public static BindableProperty IndicatorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                   propertyName: "Indicator",
                                                   returnType: typeof(bool),
                                                   declaringType: typeof(LoadingDialog),
                                                   defaultValue: null,
                                                   defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                                   propertyChanged: IndicatorPropertyChanged);

    public static BindableProperty loadtextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                                                  propertyName: "loadtext",
                                                  returnType: typeof(string),
                                                  declaringType: typeof(LoadingDialog),
                                                  defaultValue: "",
                                                  defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay,
                                                  propertyChanged: loadtextPropertyChanged);

    private static void loadtextPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (LoadingDialog)bindable;
        control.label1.Text = newValue.ToString();
    }

    public string loadtext
    {
        get { return base.GetValue(IndicatorProperty).ToString(); }
        set { base.SetValue(IndicatorProperty, value); }
    }
    private static void IndicatorPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var control = (LoadingDialog)bindable;
        control.acin.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
        control.acin.IsRunning = (bool)newValue;
        control.frame.IsVisible = (bool)newValue;
    }

    public bool Indicator
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IndicatorProperty); }
        set { base.SetValue(IndicatorProperty, value); }
    }


    public LoadingDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Now use this custom control LoadingDialog in contentpage.

```
<StackLayout>
        <local:LoadingDialog Indicator="{Binding IsVisible}" loadtext="{Binding LoadingText}" />
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        set
        {
            _isVisible = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsVisible");
        }
        get => _isVisible;
    }
    private string _loadingText = "test";
    public string LoadingText
    {
        set
        {
            _loadingText = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("LoadingText");
        }
        get => _loadingText;
    }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        IsVisible = true;
        LoadingText = "test";
        test();
    }

    public async void test()
    {
      await Task.Delay(5000);
        LoadingText = "tst20";
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        LoadingText = "tst8";
    }

}
```

The ViewModelBase is the class that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

```
 public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I haven't had the chance to try this out. but will  update you once I do, thank you